# How to fill Json Data in Dataset.xsd

Tags: c#, json, xsd, dataset

I have a webservice returning data in Json format, Now i want to populate my Dataset.xsd using the json file, how can i achieve that?

Any sort of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize it from JS to C#.  Look in to this already posted answer: [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Joshua, your method is perfect if i have to simply Deserialize JSON to a class structure, but my issue is that i want to create RDLC reports using JSON data. And RDLC reports use Dataset.xsd.